# Adding a button to a custom view in Android

Tags: android, button, custom-view

I want to add a button for this custom view.
This view is displayed via

```
setContentView(mDrawView);
```

I tried using

```
mDrawView.addView(mButton);
```

but my view does not implement the addView() function.
Is there any way to add the button? here is my drawview

```
package com.android.connect4;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

private static final int BOX_SIZE = 35;
private Paint mPaint;
private int mRow;
private int mCol;
private int mHeight;
private GameModel mGameModel;



public DrawView(Context context, int vHeight, int vWidth, GameModel vGameModel) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mGameModel = vGameModel;
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

    mHeight = vHeight;

    mRow = GameModel.ROWS;
    mCol = GameModel.COLUMNS;
    init();
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    mGameModel.attach(this);
}

private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mGameModel.UserFunction('I');
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    for(int vCount = mRow-1; vCount>=0; vCount--) 
        for(int hCount = 0; hCount<mCol; hCount++) {
            switch(mGameModel.getCellState(vCount, hCount)) {
            case GameModel.RED:
                mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawCircle(hCount*BOX_SIZE+BOX_SIZE/2, mHeight-3*BOX_SIZE-vCount*BOX_SIZE+BOX_SIZE/2, BOX_SIZE/2-5, mPaint);
                break;
            case GameModel.BLUE:
                mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                canvas.drawRect(hCount*BOX_SIZE+5, mHeight-3*BOX_SIZE-vCount*BOX_SIZE+5, hCount*BOX_SIZE+BOX_SIZE-5, mHeight-3*BOX_SIZE-vCount*BOX_SIZE+BOX_SIZE-5, mPaint);
                break;
            case GameModel.EMPTY_CELL:
                mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                canvas.drawRect(hCount*BOX_SIZE+5, mHeight-3*BOX_SIZE-vCount*BOX_SIZE+5, hCount*BOX_SIZE+BOX_SIZE-5, mHeight-3*BOX_SIZE-vCount*BOX_SIZE+BOX_SIZE-5, mPaint);
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    mPaint.setTextSize(20);
    String vShow = "";
    switch(mGameModel.getWinner()) {
    case GameModel.RED:
        vShow = "Red Wins!";
        break;
    case GameModel.BLUE:
        vShow = "Blue Wins!";
        break;
    default:
        switch(mGameModel.getCurrentPlayer()) {
        case GameModel.RED:
            vShow = "Current Player is Red";
            break;
        case GameModel.BLUE:
            vShow = "Current Player is Blue";
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    canvas.drawText(vShow, BOX_SIZE/2, (mRow+1)*BOX_SIZE, mPaint);
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    if(arg1.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    char vChar = (char) ((arg1.getRawX()/BOX_SIZE)+65);
        mGameModel.UserFunction(vChar);
        Log.i("DrawView", (int)arg1.getRawX()/BOX_SIZE+","+(int)(mHeight-arg1.getRawY())/BOX_SIZE);
//      Log.i("DrawView Char", Character.toString((char) (arg1.getRawX()/BOX_SIZE+65)));
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
}
```

I don't know how to attach this view to an xml either. Is it better to use XML instead of setContentView(mDrawView); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add views to ViewGroup. So will need to extend a view group like LinearLayout,RelativeLayout or ViewGroup. Then you will be able to add buttons to it.

Comment: Do I really need to extend one of the layout classes? Can I just instantiate any of them and add this view + a button inside?

Comment: I figure it out myself, by instantiating LinearLayout and adding the buttons inside. thanks dude!